# Why do i get TypeError in deleteDimision request using gspread (Python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to add rows and delete columns trough gspread, but i keep getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Here's the code:

```
writeTo = client.open_by_key(file['id']).worksheet('Sheet1')

request = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 8,
                    "endIndex": 26
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

result = writeTo.batch_update(request)
```

I'm using sheets API v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that `batch_update` method is the method of Class `gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet`. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_upate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update) When I saw your script, `client.open_by_key(file['id']).worksheet('Sheet1')` returnd Class `gspread.worksheet.Worksheet`. I thought that this was the reason of your issue.

  - When I tested your script, I could confirm that the same error of `TypeError: string indices must be integers` occurs.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
writeTo = client.open_by_key(file['id']).worksheet('Sheet1')
```

#### To:

```
writeTo = client.open_by_key(file['id'])
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the value of `file['id']` is the valid Spreadsheet ID. Please be careful about this. When an error like `Requested entity was not found.` occurs, please confirm your Spreadsheet ID again.
- And, I think that your request body is correct. When I tested your request body using the modified script, I confirmed that no error occurs.

#### Reference:

- [batch_update](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_upate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in `file['id']`

You can't slice a string by a character, they must be sliced via integers, like `file[5]` for example to get the first 4 letters in file.

Comment: file['id'] contains the value of the worksheet id, that line works as expected. The exception happens at the request in the result line, because of the request arguments.

Comment: Well whatever you’re doing, you’re trying to use a non integer as an index, that’s what the error is telling you. Your post doesn’t have enough information to indicate what you’re doing wrong.